# Bootstrap CSS Woes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having trouble with a website I'm making at the moment. I'm using bootstrap and on one particular page using basic bootstrap css something just won't line up.

My code is as follows :-

```
<section id="aboutUs">
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">         
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">            
        <img style="width: 500px; height: 288.31775700934577px;" src="/media/1010/macbook-front.png?width=500&amp;height=288.31775700934577" alt="" rel="1255" data-id="1255" />             
        <br />          
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">           
        <h3>Passion is what we stand for</h3>     
        <p>Manta Ray bonytail chub. Russian sturgeon yellow tang cichlid creek chub--Siamese fighting fish poacher--sablefish bichir? Bonnetmouth gray eel-catfish luminous hake frogfish rohu, eel tope snake eel clown loach northern squawfish Australian prowfish, wrymouth.</p>
        <br />            
        <blockquote>             
            <p>Good is the enemy of great</p>Innova Tamashi            
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>      
<div class="row">         
    <div class="col-lg-12">           
        <hr />         
    </div>
</div>       
<div class="row">         
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">        
        <h3>Who we are</h3>       
        <p>Enjoy smooth graphics and timeless design with Innova. Elements of different trends are blended into a special mix.</p>
    </div>       
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h3>What we do</h3>         
        <p>Enjoy smooth graphics and timeless design with Innova. Elements of different trends are blended into a special mix.</p>
    </div>         
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h3>Why we do it</h3>         
        <p>Enjoy smooth graphics and timeless design with Innova. Elements of different trends are blended into a special mix.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div></section>
```

The issue is that in the last row (which contains the 'Who we are', 'What we do') the div's all appear out of line as can be seen [here](http://4ourbusiness.azurewebsites.net/about-us/). I can't figure out why it's doing it as they should be all in line from what I can tell. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Your code is full of nonbreaking spaces (`&nbsp;`). This is causing some lines to get pushed down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the non breaking spaces `&nbsp;`.

Currently your page looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/7oe5kh9L/57/

This is the fixed page: https://jsfiddle.net/7oe5kh9L/58/

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <h3>Who we are</h3>
    <p>Enjoy smooth graphics and timeless design with Innova. Elements of different trends are blended into a special mix.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <h3>What we do</h3>
    <p>Enjoy smooth graphics and timeless design with Innova. Elements of different trends are blended into a special mix.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <h3>Why we do it</h3>
    <p>Enjoy smooth graphics and timeless design with Innova. Elements of different trends are blended into a special mix.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for that one matey. Didn't spot them. The site is in Umbraco and the WYSIWYG editor in Source Code view didn't show any &nbsp; tags.....just white space which isn't translated to spaces in HTML lol. Thanks matey :) sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the site you linked, there are lines of `&nbsp;` characters in the section in question.  Removing these will fix the misalignment issue.